# PHP MySQL Undefined index when displaying on web page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a fairly simple PHP page which displays some fields from a database.

For some reason I get:

> Notice: Undefined index: entries.id in /var/www/html/originalprices.php on line 24

I can't see whats wrong, could anyone help? Thanks

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "zxdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}     

$sql = "SELECT entries.id, entries.title,          entrytypes.text,entries.original_price, entries.budget_price,labels.name FROM entries,publishers, labels, entrytypes
where entries.entrytype_id = entrytypes.id
and publishers.entry_id = entries.id
and publishers.label_id = labels.id
and labels.id = '1371'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["entries.id"]. " - Name: " . $row["entries.title"]. "     " . $row["entrytypes.text"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I think he removed the real password for the SO posting and just missed the closing quote. I corrected with edit, and re-did error marking.

Comment: Yes, sorry the original code has the ' in it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Name of the returned field will be "id" not entries.id.

You can check that by using var_dump()

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. What do I do if I have tables which both have the same column name, can I alias them in the select and use the alias name? I tried to '+1' the answer but I'm not upto 15 points yet. Sorry PS - Its a bit hard to ever reach 15 when people mark your question '-1'

Comment: You can use an alias for the field like this

SELECT table.field othername FROM ...

the field will then be referenced as 'othername' in your PHP script.

Also, you can still mark that answer as correct without upvoting first ;)

Comment: You won't need to alias column names in this query because all the columns being returned are unique, however if you do want to alias a column name then you can do so by using `AS` then the alias after the column name, for example `SELECT entries.id AS entries_id, ...`